# Router.use() requires callback functions but got a [object Object]

Tags: express, ecmascript-6, mean-stack

I'm studying this tutorial: https://youtu.be/6Sbau-oE37w?t=5771 (1:36:00).

I guess this guy's routing works for older versions of Express, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Router.use() requires callback functions but got a [object Object]
```

I've looked into similiar questions here, but I can't understand the solution. I've tried some of the answers, with no luck so far.

My code (src/server/routes.js):

```
var usersRoutes = require('./users/routes');

module.exports = function routes(app) {
    app.use('/users', usersRoutes);
};
```

And (src/server/users/routes.js):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('./../db/db').User;
var express = require ('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello, its a test');
});
```

I'm using absolute paths in require lines, because I was getting errors otherwise. The paths are fine, but I'm missing a callback function - yet still I don't see how it should look like.

Comment: At the end of `routes.js` are you exporting the router? Make sure you do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to export the router object like so:

```
const express = require ('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello, its a test')
});

module.exports = router
```